# Dynamic cursor using a view in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, view, cursor

I am trying to write a dynamic cursor in a stored procedure using a cursor, as suggested [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?61,116597,226041). But when I try to fetch data from the cursor it seems to be blank and does not executed what is inside the loop. I confirmed this by printing inside the loop.

This is the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `rd22` ;
CREATE PROCEDURE rd22(IN unitList varchar(100), OUT dur INT)
 BEGIN
     DECLARE c, done INT;
     DECLARE cursor_end CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '02000'; 
     DECLARE v_column_val VARCHAR(50); 
     DECLARE cur_table CURSOR FOR select * from abet_view;
     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR cursor_end SET done = 1; 

set @ul = unitList;
set @qry = concat("CREATE VIEW  abet_view as SELECT abet.duration ",
 "from active_begin_end_times as abet INNER JOIN alarm_sources as a ON a.id = abet.alarm_source ",
 "and a.unit IN(",@ul,") WHERE abet.begin_timestamp = 1395874800000");    

DROP VIEW abet_view; 
prepare stmt from @qry;
execute stmt;   

OPEN cur_table; 
 FETCH cur_table INTO v_column_val; 
 WHILE done = 0 DO 
    SET c = c + v_column_val;
    FETCH cur_table INTO v_column_val; 
 END WHILE; 

 CLOSE cur_table; 

    SET dur = @c;  
END//
DELIMITER ;

SET @val = '1,2,3';
CALL rd22(@val, @dur);
```

I am writing the stored procedure for the first time, so any help is appreciable.

Cheers!

Comment: See [MariaDB/MySQL: Cursors for Dynamic SQL](https://falseisnotnull.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/mariadbmysql-cursors-for-dynamic-sql/).